# Ensures that a FS is mounted on the given mount point

Tags: mount, hard-drive

While I make some copy/paste from external into internal hard drives, some errors occurred and the device was unmounted and remounted again in a different folder. This lead to many problems as I supposed that copy/paste is done correctly...

So is there a solution to verify always that a harddrive will be mounted always at the same mount point?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is always called `/dev/sdd1` (but it probably isn't), all you need to do is add a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdd1   /media/mpdr1 ntfs   defaults,users  0   0
```

Since the device name is actually likely to change, a better way would be to use the UUID of the drive. So, first use `blkid` to get the correct UUID and then, add this line to `/etc/fstab` instead:

```
UUID=123-ABC  /media/mpdr1 ntfs defaults,users  0   0
```

The modern approach is to do all this via [`udev` rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) but that might be overkill if all you want to do is specify a mountpoint for one specific device.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command:

```
(mountpoint -q "/media/mpdr1" && df /media/mpdr1/* > /dev/null 2>&1) || ((sudo umount "/media/mpdr1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && (sudo mkdir "/media/mpdr1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || true) && sudo mount "/dev/sdd1" "/media/mpdr1")
```

Where the mount point is /media/mpdr1 and the FS is /dev/sdd1.

If the device is not properly mounted, the command tries to unmount, to create the folder (if it exists already it will also work) and finally mount the FS on the given mount point.